# Customize Netbeans' gdb session

Tags: debugging, netbeans-8

I would like to customize my remote debug session when debugging with netbeans 8 (from a windows machine).

In the gdb log, I have this line:
&"C:\Users\xxx/.gdbinit: No such file or directory.\n"

I have created such a file, but it's still ignored in my gdb session. It is probably a bug in Netbeans + Windows.

Is it possible to configure the Netbeans' gdb to use a custom configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option about the debug session in the projet properties.
Here it is possible to give a file location for the gdbinit to be loaded.

For a remote debug session the path must match a valid .gdbinit on the remote machine.[image]